# Why does reading 10 50 MB files take the same amount of time as reading one 500 MB file in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, readfile, node.js-fs

```
// fulfill one promise 5000ms
console.time('test');

(async function () {
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
  console.log('slept')
})()
  .then(() => {
    console.timeEnd('test');
  })
// Time ~5000 мс
```

```
// fulfill 10 promises by 500ms
console.time('test');

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

let test = [];

(async function () {
  test = await Promise.all(
    arr.map((elem) => new Promise(async (resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500)))
  )
  console.log(test.length)
  console.log('raided')
})()
  .then(() => {
    console.timeEnd('test');
  })

// Time ~500 мс
```

```
// Read file 500mb
const fs = require('node:fs');

console.time('test');

let test;

(async function () {
  test = fs.readFileSync('./assets/500mb');
  console.log('raided', test.length)
})()
  .then(() => {
    console.timeEnd('test');
  })
// Time ~300 мс
```

```
// Read 10 files by 50mb
const fs = require('node:fs');

console.time('test');

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

let test = [];

(async function () {
  test = await Promise.all(
    arr.map((elem) => new Promise((resolve) => fs.readFile(`./assets/50mb_${elem}`, resolve)))
  )

  console.log(test.length)
  console.log('raided')
})()
  .then(() => {
    console.timeEnd('test');
  })
// Time ~300ms
```

Having executed the first two codes, we will get a difference in execution speed of approximately 10 times. This is generally understandable. But if we read the file instead of setTimeout, we do not get this increase. Why? Explain fully, I understand that reading files is no  done by the node, but what is happening there? Why can’t we get at least a 2-fold increase? Time of the third and fourth code are the same, it makes no difference whether you read one file of 500 MB or 10 of 50 MB each. Why?

I'm trying to figure it out myself but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Because both have to actually transfer 500MB of data, regardless of how you chop it up?

Comment: There are so many things wrong in here.  Why are you wrapping `fs.readFileSync()` in an `async` function.  That makes no sense at all.  If you wan t to use promises, use `fs.promises.readFile()`.  If want to use synchronous I/O, don't wrap it in promises.

Comment: The question is not about the correctness of the code, but about the idea itself and the depth of understanding. All the explanations I see are abstract. No one can explain at the level of processes and hardware what is happening. How nodejs passed the commands to the OS in what order the OS processes it. What are we limited by hardware at this moment, in addition to the speed of reading from the disk.

Comment: With measly 500 MB files, you need to remember that disk cache in most device are already enough to handle them entirely, so you're not actually dealing with disk I/O but just RAM.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` calls a function after some time. During the time between calling `setTimeout` and the callback being called it **isn't doing any work**. It just occasionally checks the clock.

`readFile` reads a file. The callback gets called when the file has been read into memory. Reading the file **is work**. The computer can only pull data off the disk so fast. It can't read multiple files in parallel while maintaining the same number of bytes-per-second for each file as doing them one at a time. Since `readFile` is asynchronous, it doesn't block the JS event loop so the JS program can do other things at the same time (such as update the display or send messages over the network) but the disk reading part of the computer is a bottleneck for anything that wants to read from the disk.

---

If you prefer an analogy:

`setTimeout` is like saying "Ding that bell in one hour". You can just sit in a chair and wait.

`readFile` is like saying "Go to school and pick up the kids, then ding that bell", also "Go to the shops and pick up milk, then ding that bell", also "Go to the park and walk the god, then ding that bell". Each of those tasks take 1 hour, but you'll struggle to do them *all* in a single hour. You need 3 hours to do all 3.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is also abstract. I'm looking for a deeper level answer where ringing a bell makes sense to me. but how the flow goes from 10 promises to the driver that communicates with the disk is interesting. I assume that the secret is somewhere in the threads or processor cores. The process is launched on one core, therefore all manipulations with the disk will take place on one core (thread) and we do not get parallel work. But these are assumptions, no one can tell.

Comment: @AlexanderCheprasov — no, it’s a hardware issue.